# Android MonkeyRunner doesn't start

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner

Hey,
im trying to start the Monkeyrunner-Example-Project with my App.
When he trys to install the apk, it returns this error:

```
device.installPackage->
101208 13:43:52.900:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] Error starting command: monkey --port 12345
101208 13:43:52.900:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
101208 13:43:52.900:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:408)
101208 13:43:52.900:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:276)
101208 13:43:52.900:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice$1.run(AdbMonkeyDevice.java:89)
101208 13:43:52.900:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
101208 13:43:52.900:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
101208 13:43:52.900:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
101208 13:43:52.900:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
101208 13:43:52.900:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
101208 13:43:52.900:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and device.startActivity returns this:

```
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] Error executing command: am start -n de.match2blue.mobilverlieben.SignUpWizard1 
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:408)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:276)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice.shell(AdbMonkeyDevice.java:237)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice.shell(AdbMonkeyDevice.java:230)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice.startActivity(AdbMonkeyDevice.java:351)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice.startActivity(MonkeyDevice.java:297)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:175)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:355)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:215)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(C:\Users\Dustin Augstein\workspace\PythonTest\src\MonkeyTest.py:34)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(C:\Users\Dustin Augstein\workspace\PythonTest\src\MonkeyTest.py)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1197)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:538)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:156)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:101)
101208 13:44:15.233:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:212)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this errors?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [monkeyrunner fails for emulator: Error starting command: monkey --port 12345](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/64abb831392bd497) thread from the Android Developers group. It should point you in the right direction for both issues.

If you still require assistance, please provide more details (ex. show your Python script).